# Why is 'TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE' inserting an extra record (using mySQLWorkbench)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a mySQL trigger which keeps inserting an extra record and I have no idea why.

The intention of the trigger is to add a new record to an emailQueue table whenever a person completes a survey. The trigger works as expected except that it always adds an extra record on top of what is expected. It is always the same additional record that is added.

Here is the TRIGGER:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS addEmailtoQueue$$
CREATE TRIGGER addEmailtoQueue  AFTER UPDATE
    ON `Assessments`.`SURVEY_PERSON_DATE` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO emailQueue (FName,mTo) 
     SELECT FName, Email
     FROM `PERSON`  WHERE (`PERSON`.`PersonID` = NEW.`PersonID`) AND NEW.`Is_Completed`=1;
END;
$$
```

Here is the update statement:

```
UPDATE `Assessments`.`SURVEY_PERSON_DATE`
SET
`Is_Completed` = 1
WHERE `Survey_Date_ID` = 1;
```

When I run the update statement, it works as expected and enters the name and email in a new record in emailQueue. However, it then adds an additional record (always with the details of the personID=2).

Can anyone tell me why?

Note: I tested what would happen if I updated the 'Is_Completed' field back to '0' - It doesn't create a new record for the field I updated (which is correct) but is does still create the same extra record.

Here are the tables scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE `PERSON` (
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FName` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LName` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Email` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Username` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `UserType` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `SURVEY_PERSON_DATE` (
  `Survey_Date_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PersonID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SurveyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Is_Completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Survey_Date_ID`),
  KEY `PersonID` (`PersonID`),
  KEY `SurveyID` (`SurveyID`),
  CONSTRAINT `SURVEY_PERSON_DATE_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonID`) REFERENCES `PERSON` (`PersonID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `SURVEY_PERSON_DATE_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SurveyID`) REFERENCES `SURVEY` (`SurveyID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `emailQueue` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Fname` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mFrom` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'terence@consisco.com',
  `mTo` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mCC` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mBCC` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mSubject` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mBody` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `added_by` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `email_sent` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `send_tried` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `send_result` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `PERSON` VALUES (1,'Terence',NULL,'terence@terencesweeney.com',NULL,NULL,NULL),(2,'Axel',NULL,'Axel@foley.com',NULL,NULL,NULL),(3,'Terence',NULL,'terence@terencesweeney.com',NULL,NULL,NULL),(4,'Terry',NULL,'terry@terry.com',NULL,NULL,NULL),(5,'Terry',NULL,'terry@terry.com',NULL,NULL,NULL),(6,'Terry1',NULL,'1terry@terry.com',NULL,NULL,NULL);

INSERT INTO `SURVEY_PERSON_DATE` VALUES (1,6,1,1,'2020-08-09 08:36:42','2020-08-10 05:17:49'),(30,3,1,0,'2020-08-10 05:17:49','2020-08-10 05:17:49');
```

Comment: *Here are the tables:* Please replace (or add) table form data with their CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the heads up. This is the first time I have generated these scripts so please let me know if there is anything else I need to add.

Comment: UPDATE. I was previously trying on mySQLWorkbench. I just tried running the update query on phpAdmin and it works fine. I have gone back again and tested on Workbench but the same problem arises. Any idea why workbench would have the problem but not phpAdmin?

Comment: Not reproduced. [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/41vQXxKsB7VBxFD9JnWdGJ/0) (FKs removed, DB aliases removed). *Any idea why workbench would have the problem but not phpAdmin?* Really this may be workbench issue... no idea. Except "do not use (too smart) GUI" :)

Comment: Okay thanks. I have changed the question title just in case someone else knows.